# Gatling: Access variables from saved "findAll" list in foreach loop

Tags: scala, foreach, gatling, findall, scala-gatling

I'm new to Gatling and Scala, and I had a hopefully quick and basic question about how to access the elements that are saved as from a `findAll` in the previous request.

The regex in the below code matches multiple button values. I eventually want to find the "max" button value (by something I'll come up with later), and based on that use that button in subsequent requests. However, I'm unable to actually access the values in `button_list`. In the terminal when I try to print the values, the values don't get substituted and literally print like this for each button:

```
Button ${count}: ${button}
Button ${count}: ${button}
```

Here's the snippet producing this:

```
...
        .exec(http("click_ok")
            .post("www.foo.com")
            .headers(headers_0)
            .formParam("_flowExecutionKey", "${flow_execution_key}")
            .formParam("_eventId_submit", "${_eventId_submit}")
            .check(regex("""foo(.*?)bar""").findAll.saveAs("button_list"))).exitHereIfFailed
        .pause(1)
        .foreach("${button_list}", "button", "count") {
            exec(session => {
                println("Button ${count}: ${button}")
            session})
        }
...
```

When I see the `session` print out in the logs, I can see that the buttons have matched and the session contains a list like the following, so I know there are successful matches:

```
button_list -> List(c11/98/280, c11/98/390)
```

Anyone have an example or know what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the [official documentation](https://gatling.io/docs/current/session/expression_el/), Gatling Expression Language is not something that magically works anywhere. It only works when passing such String to a Gatling DSL method, not in your own code. You must use the [Gatling Session API](https://gatling.io/docs/current/session/session_api/).

Comment: Wow, thanks for this! Will give it a shot. This is not mentioned on the "Advanced Tutorial" page at all! I wonder if I should take a break and read all the documentation through. Small speed bump though - Gatling is so much more pleasant than Loadrunner

Comment: Well, hard to have every possibly useful knowledge fit in those 2 tutorials. We hope to be able to revisit some day. Indeed, taking 1 hours to read the rest of the doc would be very beneficial. Thanks for your kind words!